# JQUERY + Are there any Child DIV's

Tags: jquery

I have a DIV like this:

```
 <div id="containerContent"></div>
```

Sometimes there are child DIV's within the above DIV and sometimes not.
I need a way to check if there are NO child DIV's within "containerContent" DIV so I can then perform an action.

I've tried this unsuccessfully:

```
 if(!$('div#containerContent').children('div')) {
      alert('missing');
 }
```

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `children()` method returns a jQuery object which will always evaluate to `true`. Use the `length` property to determine the number of elements contained within the object.

```
if(!$('div#containerContent').children('div').length) {
    alert('missing');
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be if($('div#containerContent').children('div').length > 0) then?

Comment: @MartijnB No, that would be the opposite to what the OP wants. If `length` is 0, the negation at the start (`!`) will branch to the `alert()`

Comment: Sorry you're right, I read it wrong and didn't know that (!0) {} is possible. +1 For waking me up and learning me something new.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
var container = $('#containerContent');
if (!container.is(':has(div)')) {
    // missing
}
```

Note that this will check all descendant elements, not just immediate children.